# Javascript = AddEventlistener only working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I would like to use a listener that would trigger a function when the mouse leaves the screen. I'm using the following code:

```
content = 'blabla';
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){ display_exit(content);  });
function display_exit(content)
{ console.log(content); }
```

When I execute this code on Chrome, it works while on Firefox or Explorer/Edge, nothing happens.

Is there something in my syntax that Chrome is forgiving and not the others?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: [Works in FF for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/hmypejo2/)

Comment: Andy, you used `mouseout` there, not `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event is only [specified for](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mouseleave) nodes of type [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), not for `Node` or [`Documents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document):

> **Type**  mouseleave
>
> ...
>
> **Trusted Targets**   Element
>
> ...

You can attach the listener to the `documentElement` and it shall work:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("mouseout", ...);
```

Further, ensure the document (the `html` element) has 100% height, otherwise, depending on the content it might not have even entered the document element, thus no leave can be triggered.

See this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b3wtoayq/

According to the spec I presume it's a bug in Chrome allowing to attach the event listener to the document itself.

Comment: That's brilliant, it's exactly what I need. I tried alternatives with mouseout but I did not manage to do exactly what I wanted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

"mouseleave" events are fired by `Element` objects and do not bubble. A document (`document`) is not an `Element` and so attaching an event listener to it to listen for "mousemove" events, has no effect, because of the combination of the above two factors.

This has nothing to do with Firefox. It's by design, as proposed by a Web standard body, W3C in this case. If anything, Firefox adheres to the specification, something that cannot be said about Chrome, evidently.

Always consult the authorative reference on the technology you're using before putting it to use and questioning the behavior you yourself assume is wrong: [UI Events, W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-mouseleave) (that MDN, among others, uses as source)

The solution is to amend your code, making do with [the "mouseout" event instead, which *does* bubble](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-mouseout), or be attaching your event listener(s) to *elements* (e.g. `document.documentElement`) instead of a document.